# Scala opening write to stdout or file

Tags: java, scala, io, stdout

Let's say I have a function

```
writeToFileOrStdout(fname: String = Nil) = { ... }
```

If the user passes a string value for fname, then I'd like to open a file with that name and write to it; otherwise, I'd like to print to stdout. I could always just write an if statement to take care of this, but how would I write a case statement on fname and open the correct corresponding outputStream?

```
    val outStream = fname match {
      case Nil => ???
      case _   => new java.io.FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(fname))
    }
    outStream.write( ... )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not rewrite the function as:

```
def writeToFileOrStdout(fname: Option[String] = None) = {
  val outStream = fname match{
    case Some(name) => new java.io.FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(name))
    case None => System.out
  }
  ...
}
```

It's always a good idea to use `Option` for an optional input as opposed to using `null`.  That's basically what it's there for.  In good scala code, you will not see explicit references to `null`.

In fact, your code doesn't even compile for me.  `Nil` is used to represent an empty list, not a null or non supplied `String`.

Answer (score 2):

To augment cmbaxter's response...

Mapping a `String` with a possible `null` value to `Option[String]` is trivial: `Option(stringValue)` will return `None` where `stringValue` is `null`, and `Some(stringValue)` where non-null.

Thus, you can either:

1. `writeToFileOrStdout(Option(stringValue))`, or
2. If you're stuck on `String` (and possibly a `null` value) as the parameter to `writeToFileOrStdout`, then internally use `Option(fname)` and match to what it returns::

   ```
   def writeToFileOrStdout(fname: String = null) = {
     val outStream = Option(fname) match{
       case Some(name) => new java.io.FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(name))
       case None => System.out
     }
     ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To further augment cmbaxter's response, you might consider writing this:

```
def filenameToOutputStream(name: String) = 
  new java.io.FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(name))

def writeToFileOrStdout(fname: Option[String] = None) = {
  val outStream = fname map filenameToOutputStream getOrElse System.out
  ...
}
```

As the post [*Idiomatic Scala: Your Options Do Not Match*](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/06/15/idiomatic-scala-your-options-do-not-match/) suggests, this might be more idiomatic Scala.